# Swing components automatically changes to AWT

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

I need to call the LOGIN page from the default class and work on it but when I call it, the Swing components in the next page changes to AWT.

```
public class Demo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        new LOGIN().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: *"Swing components automatically changes to AWT"* That's most likely **not** what is happening. Instead it sounds as though the default Metal look and feel is used in the IDE, while the Jar is (for whatever reason) using the native look and feel. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: "Swing components.... changes to AWT"  how do you know that ?

Comment: Look and feel of the components changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check on which class and methods do the suggestion and autocomplete calls before you implement them.